# Aligning two TextViews in Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-5.0-lollipop, android-relativelayout

I have two TextViews aligned in the "row", using the following layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/wrapper"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/big_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
            android:textSize="21sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/small_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

But, what happens is that since the left one is larger than the right one, the result looks like this (picture is just for illustration):

[image: Bad behaviour]

Instead, this is what I'm looking for:

[image]

Tried adding gravity="bottom" to the small TextView but it didn't work.
Also tried to wrap the small TextView in another layout, set it's layout height to match_parent (so it would take the height of the big TextView) and then set the small TextView gravity to bottom, but it also didn't work.

Edit:
plot twist: how to align it to the CENTER of the big TextView?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this line to your smaller `textview`

```
android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/big_text"
```

or

```
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/big_text"
```

like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/wrapper"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/big_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
            android:textSize="21sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/small_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/big_text" 
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Btw, just interested, how to aling to CENTER of big TextView instead of the bottom?

Comment: you can use this android:layout_centerVertical="true"  in your second textview as you are using relative layout as parent

Answer (score 0):

Try it in the second textview

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/small_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/big_text"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/big_text"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:text="BIG"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="small"
            android:textSize="15sp"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```